# Right laptop speaker starts playing sound only after the left one

Tags: drivers, sound, speakers

Occasionally, when playing a sound my right speaker takes a second or less to start playing that sound while the left one starts right away. They are in synch but it's noticeable when the the right one "kicks in".

I'm running a fresh install of Ubuntu 18.04.4 (checked the third-party driver option) in my MSI GE72 2QL Apache laptop.

Running `lspci -v` gives me 2 audio devices:

```
00:03.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Broadwell-U Audio Controller (rev 0a)
    Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] Broadwell-U Audio Controller
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 34
    Memory at a3314000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel

00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset High Definition Audio Controller (rev 05)
    Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset High Definition Audio Controller
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 31
    Memory at a3310000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel
```

Comment: I'm not sure but I think the problem is the power save settings. At the moment, I've added `options snd-hda-intel power_save=0 power_save_controller=N` to `/etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf`. If it doesn't work, I'll update the question.

Comment: Suggest, for troubleshooting purposes only, download a 'flavour' of 19.10 with a different Desktop Environment from https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours and boot from a LiveUSB made with that different distro. The ISO uses to make a LiveUSB should be checked for download errors by https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-how-to-verify-ubuntu#0 . Make a LiveUSB following these instructions on another Linux PC https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu#0 or on a Windows PC https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-windows#0 .

Answer (score 0):

A few days have passed and I can say with confidence the problem is gone.

As stated in my comment, the solution was to disable the **power save mode** for the **audio** by adding the line `options snd-hda-intel power_save=0 power_save_controller=N` to the file `/etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf`.

For future people having the same problem, first you must discover your audio driver by running `lspci -v` and looking for the audio. In my case it was `snd-hda-intel`. Additionally, I know some don't use alsa, so you must search how to disable the power save and power save controller on whatever it is you're using.

As a side note, this also happened to me in Windows. The problem and its cause were the same, so if you have this in Windows, search how to disable these settings (it involves messing with the registry).